# Why does Array#delete skip "blue" and print "green" when I delete "green?"

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

```
array=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
array.each do | color |
  puts(color)
  if color == 'green'
    array.delete(color)
  end
end
```

This prints red, green, purple. I get it that somehow array.delete messes up the iteration, but my question is why and how? What's going on behind the hood? If I replace array.delete(color), with, say, array << 'white', then all colors will be printed, so this behavior seems to occur only when an item is deleted from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original `array`, `green` is in `1` index. Thus on the second iteration, while your `if` expression evalued as `true`, you are deleting the actual entry `green` from the original `array`. Thus `blue` comes into the index `1`. That's why, in the third iteration, `3`rd element is `purple`, and that's how you are missing `"blue"` from your expected output.

You can debug it as below :-

```
array=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']
array.each do | color |
  if color == 'green'
    array.delete(color)
  end
  # printing array to debug the actual array content after each iteration
  p array
end
# >> ["red", "green", "blue", "purple"]
# >> ["red", "blue", "purple"]
# >> ["red", "blue", "purple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutate your array *before* you iterate and dynamically change your indices within your loop. For example:

```
array = %w[red green blue purple]
array.delete 'green'
array.each { |color| puts color }
```

This correctly yields:

```
$ ruby colors.rb 
red
blue
purple
```